# How to set wait timeout for a queue in Amazon redshift?

Tags: amazon-redshift

I know there exists a wlm timeout which times out when the query 'executes' more than that time. But can i set a timeout for the amount of time a query waits in the queue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can control the amount of time that query spends waiting in queue indirectly by specifying statement_timeout configuration parameter on session or whole cluster level in addition to max_execution_time parameter on WLM level. If both WLM timeout (max_execution_time) and statement_timeout are specified, the shorter timeout is used. In this case the maximum time that query will be able to wait in the queue is "statement_timeout" minus "max_execution_time".

Comment: max_execution_time includes the time that the query spent sitting in a queue?

Comment: Answer is correct see Docs for set statement_timeout https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_statement_timeout.html Note that `max_execution_time` is deprecated, it says use `query_execution_time`. It also says that neither of those include planning, queuing wait time, only execution time. The `statement_timeout` is the only one that does include the queue wait time. I don't see it as feasible to run (for 5 mins) `SET statement_timeout TO 300000` for every user session but if you query the `stv_recents` view you'll see that's exactly what the AWS system user rdsdb does.

Comment: I think this is incorrect: `the maximum time that query will be able to wait in the queue is "statement_timeout" minus "max_execution_time"`. The two limits are evaluated completely separately: the statement_timeout limit is evaluated on the entire time irrespective of queue or exec time; the max_execution_time/query_execution_time limit is evaluated on exec time irrespective of any other time.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your WLM configuration to create separate queues for the queries on the basis of time they require to run and at runtime, you can route queries to the queues according to user groups or query groups. Hope that is what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but i don't want to set the execution timeout. i want to set a timeout for the time the query is waiting in its respective queue. The wlm configuration has an execution timeout only.